# MSSQL 2008. I can't find Login for particular database user

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

I found a user in mssql 2008 database - domain\testuser2 with login domain\testuser2.

But I couldn't find this login by using Mssql Management Studio or in the system tables (sys.server_principals, sys.syslogins, sys.linked_logins, sys.remote_logins).

When I try to make another user with this login (CREATE USER _test FOR login [domain\testuser2]), the error is following: The login already has an account under a different user name.

So, this login is exist. Where could I find it? Is there some system tables or views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

In MSSQL you can create database users with Windows Authentification *without* logins.

For example, you can successfully execute the following sql-query (even you haven't sql-login [MyDomainName\myWinLogin])

```
CREATE USER [MyDomainName\myWinLogin]
```